# about sessionDelegate of facebook SDK

Tags: facebook

I introduced Facebook SDK according to the following procedures.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#register

However, in the portion of sessionDelegate, the following errors can come out and cannot be solved.

> sessionDelegate = _sessionDelegate
>
> (error)Existing ivar '_sessionDelegate' for unsafe_unretained property
>   'sessionDelegate' must be __unsafe_unretained

Since a cause is not known at all, if known by some people, please let me know.